# Column update and insert 2 rows within the same table

Tags: sql

I have a table named `table1` and the value in one `columnA` is `X`.  So when this value is `X` we need to insert 2 new rows and update the `columnA` with values `Z` and `Y`.

Is it possible with an `insert` and `Update` statement?

I am thinking of below query to update the column but how to insert the two rows.

```
select * from table1 where columnA = 'x'
Update columnA ='Z'
```

Comment: What seems to be a problem? Do you know how to insert 1 row?

Comment: Yes i know how to insert 1 row but there are so many columns in the table. Normal Insert statement we use Insert into table1 (column1,column2.....) values(value1,value2.....);

Comment: You control what fields get values during insert, others will get a default value.

Comment: Is it possible with any other  statements other insert?

Comment: Would you please provide an example of how to 'insert 2 new rows and update the columnA with values Z and Y' ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following statements to insert in the table

```
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT 'y' columnA,
       columnB,
       columnC,
       ...
  FROM table1
 WHERE columnA = 'x';

INSERT INTO table1
SELECT 'z' columnA,
       columnB,
       columnC,
       ...
  FROM table1
 WHERE columnA = 'x';
```

But of course, you still need to provide criteria in WHERE clause to get the specific data you wanted replicated in the same table but with different columnA value. You really need to specify each column.

Comment: I want to update the column with y and z values adding 2 new rows. But here you are using a select statement. it's not working

Comment: Can you please provide a sample original data and result data?